# EF Core async client side evaluation

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Working with `net5.0`. So I have this query:

```
context.DbSet
  .Where() // server side
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where() // can't be translated to SQL so client side
  .ToList();
```

So how can we achieve an async variant of this? I would assume it would work like this:

```
await context.DbSet
  .Where() // server side
  .AsAsyncEnumerable()
  .Where() // can't be translated to SQL so client side
  .ToListAsync();
```

But that doesn't work. What is the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Explicit client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation) section of the EF Core documentation, the EF Core team vision is that

> If you are using `AsAsyncEnumerable` and want to compose the query further on client side then you can use [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) library which defines operators for async enumerables. For more information, see [client side linq operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async#client-side-async-linq-operators).

So by idea you need to install that package and use

```
await context.DbSet
  .Where() // server side
  .AsAsyncEnumerable()
  .Where(...) // this is provided by System.Interactive.Async
  .ToList(); // as well this
```

Just please note that there is some method naming clash when you reference both packages (`System.Interactive.Async` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, because EF Core `DbSet<T>` implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which makes some extension method calls ambiguous), so you might start getting compile time errors. There are open issues in their GitHub issue trackers, but neither team is willing to fix them saying that the problem is caused by the other. One of the drawbacks of the open source policy utilized recently by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks. This code is in my repository and for it to work I need to reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` that is an unfortunate thing. Any way to specify which namespace to pick on particular extension methods?

Comment: As soon as you don't reference `DbSet`s **inside** your queries, you'll be fine. For instance `from a db.Set<A>() join b in db.Set<B>() ...` - `A` is ok since it is query root, but `B` would produce ambiguity. It can be solved though by applying `AsQueryable()` on it inside the query, i.e. `from a db.Set<A>() join b in db.Set<B>().AsQueryable() ...` will be fine.

Comment: In most of the cases, if you utilize navigation properties instead of manual joins, which is the preferred way of doing joins in Linq to Entities, you won't notice that issue at all.

Comment: Yeah found some cases in by code. Using `AsQueryable()` solved it. Thank